# NSwag / OpenAPI - Shared / common type definitions

Tags: typescript, namespaces, swagger, nswag

We got a scenario with a multitude of microservices, which shares a lot of common types / DTOs.

We're using NSwag for SwaggerDoc / JSON, which works great.

However, when generating TypeScript clients, these types gets redefined for each service in their respective directories, hence duplicates.

Is there a clean way of discriminating these types, in a way that the TypeScript generator can e.g separate these to a common directory/namespace on the client ?

I'm thinking something like using an NSwag processor (e.g SchemaProcessor) in the backend, otherwise I can't see an obvious way to approach this.